# Werewolf: the Apocalypse auspice name etymologies

Tags: world-of-darkness, terminology, werewolf-the-apocalypse

As part of his question about [the etymologies of the auspice names in *Werewolf: The Forsaken*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/39416/werewolf-the-forsaken-auspice-names-etymology), @OpaCitiZen discusses the origins of "theurge":

> What I'm looking for: I remember, for example, that the word "theurge" (used in the oWoD Werewolf, also an auspice) comes from "theurgy", which Google defines as "the operation or effect of a supernatural or divine agency in human affairs" and, still according to Google, has its roots in the Greek "theos" (god) and "-ergos" (working), which combine into "theourgia" (sorcery), which makes it pretty obvious why the designers of that game picked it.

Now, [in my answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/39417/50), I noted that the Forsaken names are the Apocalypse names gone backward through Grimm's Law. But that begs the question of just what the Apocalypse auspice names mean. So, given that, from where do Ragabash, Galliard, Philodox, and Ahroun come?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the answers I have so far:

- "Ragabash" is English; it means "ragamuffin" or "[A shiftless, disreputable fellow](http://www.finedictionary.com/Ragabash.html)."
- "Galliard" is from Old French; it means "[lively, brisk, high-spirited](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Galliard)." [It's also a dance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galliard).
- "Philodox" goes back to Greek, meaning "opinion-lover." [Someone enraptured with his own ideas](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/philodox).
- "Ahroun" is of unknown provenance, but probably [onomatopoeia for a Garou's howl to the moon](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rec.games.frp.storyteller/Y7crcslxm0o/rrHcAwyteqAJ).

Comment: With regards to "Ahroun". do you have anything to support that? Like a note from the game designers...

Comment: Nothing like that -- the attribution dates back to a WW lingo FAQ from 1996 on Usenet. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rec.games.frp.storyteller/Y7crcslxm0o/rrHcAwyteqAJ I have found no contradictory information, and no analogues in other languages. Plus, it's so intuitively right that I believe I recall a WWer confirming it back in the day. I'll upvote someone who gets a better answer, but it passes my smell test.

Comment: @Discord In portuguese, at least, the "Wolf howl" is treated like "Auuuuuooooooooo", so it really makes sense. Also, if you ever read a real wolf howling and tried to make the same sounds by yourself, "Auuurooooooooonnn" it's really close to what you would get.

Comment: I wasn't trying to dispute anything, just curious. :) As that Usenet FAQ points out, WW used a lot of actual, albeit archaic, words. It seemed a little strange that they just made one up, but it is a pretty perfect fit.

Answer (score -3):

Google translate seems to think Ahroun is the Arabic for Aaron.
But wikipedia says Harun is the Arabic for Aaron
However, the "divine rage" of Aaron is really better embodied in the tribe of Levi as a whole, but Aaron's grandson Phineas really does take the cake for dick moves in history.
So to me at least, I can understand why the word 'Ahroun' might be evoke the idea of violence getting out of hand.